# When browser size get smaller website 'moves up'

Tags: browser, web

I really dont know what is causing this problem, but when I make the browser window smaller you can see the website move upwards slightly(about 30px). Vice versa, when you open the browser window you can see the website move downward.

Help?

www.for-instance.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following style:

```
body {
    ...
    margin: 3.5% auto;
    ...
}
```

The percent is measuring the total height of the browser, and changing it that way. Set it to pixel-based height, and you will see that it sits still.

Comment: Hehe, these things happen! :)